# asp.net Can I disable datagrid sorting action once button onclick?

Tags: c#, asp.net, servlets, datagrid

I have encountered a problem concerning element "asp:datagrid".

For example, i have declared a datagrid in my servlet, and set AllowSorting="True"

And i have a button, say "button1", to update data to the database base on the selected record of the datagrid.

May i ask if i can DISABLE "button1" (which is before postback of the servlet, disabled immediately after user click one of the header of the datagrid for sorting), to prevent user to commit update to the database ?

And also can i DISABLE SORTING action of the datagrid (also before postback) when "button1" was clicked ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also enable/disable controls and events programmatically. So in the sort method add this to disable sorting after the first click.

```
DataGrid1.AllowSorting = false;
```

To disable controls

```
Button1.Enabled = false;
```

To disable using a jQuery listener. You can disable the sorting links the easiest by binding a listener to the class, in this case `SortingLink`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= Button1.ClientID %>').click(function () {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });

    $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> .SortingLink').click(function () {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: However, if i add the above code in my c# program, it seems that they have no effect on the html element before the servlet re-render the html page (which is done after the postback). My aim is to disable the html element instantly after user click on sorting or click on button1

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, really struggle to figure out different kinds of solution to solve the problem. BTW thanks for your answer and it actually work when i add it to my servlet